# Reference resource id from resource

Tags: android, android-resources, android-productflavors

I have a project with multiple flavors, `apple` and `banana`. It references a file that is stored in the `raw` resource directory. I would prefer to avoid naming each one `database.sqlite` and instead keep the name relevant to the flavor, `apple.sqlite` and `banana.sqlite`. In my code, I have a line that reads as

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.apple);
```

Is it possible to create an integer resource that could essentially link to the right id, or would I be better off making a class in each flavor that would have the link to it?

Comment: You should be able to set up something like `apple/res/values/ids.xml`, with an `<item type="raw" name="whatever">@raw/apple</item>` element, plus `banana/res/values/ids.xml`, with an `<item type="raw" name="whatever">@raw/banana</item>`. Then, have your code refer to `R.raw.whatever`. Basically, you're looking for [resource aliases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) for raw resources, and I think that what I have is the right syntax for that, though I am not 100% certain.

Comment: It'll be a while before I can test it, but this looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @CommonsWare That was a perfect solution. If you want to make it an answer I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dedicated source sets for build types, product flavors (such as `apple` and `banana`), and build variants. You can create [resource aliases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources), to give a resource another identifier. You should be able to mash these up to get what you want.

I assume, from your question, that you have `apple/res/raw/apple.sqlite` and `banana/res/raw/banana.sqlite` in your project. If so, then:

- Create `apple/res/values/ids.xml`, and in there have `<item type="raw" name="whatever">@raw/apple</item>`
- Create `banana/res/values/ids.xml`, and in there have `<item type="raw" name="whatever">@raw/banana</item>`
- Use `R.raw.whatever` to identify this resource in your code in `main`

(where you can replace `whatever` with, like, whatever)

Here, you are setting up a common alias (`whatever`) for the resource, pointing the flavor-specific definition of the alias to the flavor-specific resource.